# Mongodb _id Value and Indexes Are Lost During Mongorestore

Tags: backup, mongodb, restore, mongodump, mongorestore

Steps I used:

1. `mongodump`
2. copy dump folder to another computer (for each collection I get .bson and metadata files)
3. `mongorestore` myDumpFolder

I noticed the indexes are lost and `_id` has new values after `mongorestore`.

Can anyone share their restore experiences that restored both indexes and mongodb_id?

Comment: mongorestore should recreate all indexes what mongodump has recorded. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/index.html

Comment: Show "step by step" what you think you have done. As was noted when you posted on stackoverflow, missing fields and indexes are actually properties of `mongoexport ` and `mongoimport`, and to get anything "close to" what you actually don't describe very well here, you need to force it by specific options

Comment: I got my indexes and _id back when I re-restored databases using the same folder with ```mongorestore```. I am guessing index and _id were lost because the database and collections were created when I run my backend application which happened before ```mongorestore```

Comment: Confirmed that indexes and ```_id``` will be lost if database and collections are created before ```mongorestore```.Thanks everyone who looked into this problem!

Answer (score 3):

Can anyone share their restore experiences that restored both indexes and mongodb_id?

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/) By default, [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore) looks for a database backup in the dump/ directory.

New in version 3.6:

All MongoDB collections have UUIDs by default. When MongoDB restores collections, the restored collections retain their original UUIDs. When restoring a collection where no UUID was present, MongoDB generates a UUID for the restored collection.

**UUID()** has the following syntax:

```
UUID(<string>)

Parameter   Type    Description
hex        string   
                    Optional. Specify a 36 character string to convert to a UUID BSON object. If not provided, MongoDB generates a random UUID in RFC 4122 v4 format.

Changed in version 3.6: In earlier versions of the mongo shell, UUID required a hexadecimal string argument. See the 3.4 manual.
```

It's returns **`A BSON UUID object`**.

> I noticed the indexes are lost and _id has new values after
> mongorestore.

@Will, As JJussi has already said that mongorestore should recreate all indexes what mongodump has recorded.

**For Example**

I have mongodump in my `C:\data\dump` folder. Which contains the database  folder **`100YWeatherSmall`**,**`citibike`**,**`city`**,**`ships`**,**`video`** with their (**.bson** & **.json**) file. These database I had already restored in MongoDB 3.6.
[image]

Here again i am going to mongorestore to these databases dump file in MongoDB 3.6.

As you can see that mention all databases has already in MongoDB.

[image]

**Note:** Here I have highlighted the some database name due to security reason.

Here I am going to mongorestore through the below command.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongorestore --verbose C:\data\dump
```

> **Note:**  Run mongorestore from the system command line, not the mongo shell.

**`video.movies`** database dump restore report status

```
- E11000 duplicate key error collection: video.movies index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('58c59c6b99d4ee0af9e0eef0') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: video.movies index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('58c59c6b99d4ee0af9e0eef1') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: video.movies index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('58c59c6b99d4ee0af9e0eef2') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: video.movies index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('58c59c6b99d4ee0af9e0eef3') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: video.movies index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('58c59c6b99d4ee0af9e0eef4') }
```

**`100YWeatherSmall.data`** database dump restore report status

```
- E11000 duplicate key error collection: 100YWeatherSmall.data index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5553a98ee4b02cf7150e1cc8') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: 100YWeatherSmall.data index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5553a98ee4b02cf7150e1cca') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: 100YWeatherSmall.data index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5553a98ee4b02cf7150e1ccc') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: 100YWeatherSmall.data index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5553a98ee4b02cf7150e1ccd') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: 100YWeatherSmall.data index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5553a98ee4b02cf7150e1cd0') }
```

**`citibike.trips`** database dump restore report status

```
 - E11000 duplicate key error collection: citibike.trips index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('572bb8232b288919b68b258e') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: citibike.trips index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('572bb8232b288919b68b25ad') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: citibike.trips index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('572bb8232b288919b68b2608') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: citibike.trips index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('572bb8232b288919b68b26c5') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: citibike.trips index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('572bb8232b288919b68b26da') }
```

Here you can noticed that all during `mongorestore` it's showing  `index: _id_ dup key:` because that **index: *id*** is already exist in that database & collection .

That means whatever mongodump has created the index:*id* & ObjectId that is same index:*id* & ObjectId is same mongorestore in MongoDB.

Here the below mention reports is the citibike.trips mongorestore complete mongodump restore reports.

```
2018-05-30T10:56:31.962+0300    [########################]  citibike.trips  835MB/835MB  (100.0%)
2018-05-30T10:56:31.962+0300    restoring indexes for collection citibike.trips from metadata
2018-05-30T10:56:32.106+0300    finished restoring citibike.trips (1990273 documents)
2018-05-30T10:56:32.126+0300    done
```

For example here I have only mention the citibite.trips restore complete reports. The message is showing **restoring indexes for collection citibike.trips from metadata**.

So, as per above conclusion we can say that `mongorestore`, store the same `index:_id_` & `ObjectId`,  which `mongodump` has created.

For your further ref [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) , [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/databases-and-collections/#collections)